# Send HTTP request with Header using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, http-headers

I'm trying to send the following http request to twitter api in order to get the top trending topics back

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Authorization':'bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA************************X3jdHnTJ5GXDWBj',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            method: 'GET'
        });
</script>
```

And yet, I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is my first time working with JS setting headers and such. I tried sending the request using https://www.hurl.it/ and it returned the results correctly.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header not a request header.  Are you sure that API is usable from JavaScript?

Comment: It seems that you dont  have any access to this api make sure it is accesible

Comment: @HassanTariq it is accessible..

Comment: try removing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',

Comment: @HassanTariq I did, didn't work.